# invalid rows qty on catalog_category_product_index table after reindexing in magento2

Tags: magento2, indexing

I have imported large product qty with custom magmi port for magento2:

```
MariaDB [magento2]> select count(*) from catalog_product_entity;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|  9974308 |
+----------+
1 row in set (2.45 sec)
```

Only one store view in this magento instance and lots of categories created (about 100k products in each category) which admin backend shows.

But after reindexing I saw that only 500 records are returned but block collection from each category, and then I realized that `catalog_category_product_index` was built incorrectly...

```
MariaDB [magento2]> select distinct count(product_id) from catalog_category_product_index;
+-------------------+
| count(product_id) |
+-------------------+
|            105179 |
+-------------------+
```

How to debug and resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's known issue https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/8018.
It have long description of problem

Comment: any change to get partial indexing working ? on `isRangingNeeded ` returning `false` on 9mln of products still getting `The table 'catalog_category_product_index_tmp' is full` even when i tuned maximum temporary table size...